# Detect start and end of a processing task in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm doing image editing using the canvas. Consider the following code:

```
ctx.drawImage(  // <-- start point of the task which causes the browser to lag
    image,
    crop.x * scaleX,
    crop.y * scaleY,
    crop.width * scaleX,
    crop.height * scaleY,
    0,
    0,
    crop.width * scaleX,
    crop.height * scaleY,
);             // <-- end of the task
```

Is there a way that I could detect start and end point of a intensive process? My goal is to show a loading indicator, something like Photoshop when you open a large photo. And hopefully keep the whole page responsive and not lag completely.

Comment: you could see what tasks are taking time in the chrome debugger, and then show loading around those tasks, infact the chrome debugger is so powerful it will even give you heap snapshots and what not

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar thank you, that should help. the browser support would be a problem though. i thought js would have an api for such things.

Comment: you'd need to do some research for that, and again, i highly doubt it would be available for older browsers

Comment: How big are your images? I can’t imagine that just drawing an image takes so much time.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff that code is only a part of the project. there is a lot of pixel manipulation going on. the site is in persian but [take a look here](https://negar.vercel.app/tools/filter) and just choose an image.

Comment: I tried but after choosing an image nothing happens